# Laravel - Default connexion cannot be set

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[UPDATE] php artisan cache:clear solved it!

I have two databases, which I call mysql1 and mysql2
For some reason if I don't specify the connection, i get "Database [mysql] not configured."

In database.php I have this

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql1'),      *// here I replaced it by 'default' => 'mysql1' to be sure, same effect*

'connections' => [

        'mysql1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'MYDB1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'MYDB2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

In my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql1
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=races
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=null

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2
DB_HOST_SECOND=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=itra
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=null
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true
```

So i always need to specify

```
DB::connection('mysql1')->select
```

Any idea what i forgot? for info, mysql isn't set anywhere at all...

Comment: Did you run `php artisan config:clear` after those changes?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.